# Do not create data source bean for test classes or based on some config - spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-el

Some context:
I have a lot of legacy testcases which runs the whole spring boot application when they run.
I have ConfigProperties class that fetches variable from a secure cloud config server which stores the database url, name, password, etc.

```
class ConfigProperties
{
// database info coming from secure config cloud server
 String username;
 String password;
 String url;
...
}
```

I have some configuration class that contains a datasource bean.

```
@Configuration
class DataSourceConfig
{
    @Autowired
    ConfigProperties configProperties;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(configProperties.getUsername()).password(configProperties.getPassword()).url(configProperties.getUrl()).build();
    }
}
```

Now when I run my testcases, it loads whole spring boot app and the testcases fail because it can't connect to database since it can't find username, password and url (null).

Now I don't want to create this bean dataSource when username of ConfigProperties is null.

Some of my failed solutions:

**1st failed solution**
I tried doing that by adding @Conditional(SomeDataSouceConditionClass.class) on my bean and SomeDataSouceConditionClass looked something like this:

```
class SomeDataSouceConditionClass implements Condition
{

    @Autowired
    ConfigProperties configProperties;
    
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return configProperties.getUrl() != null;
    }
}
```

Now the problem here is that the field configProperties is null since it can't find configProperties bean in spring ioc. As a result I get NullPointerException.

**2nd failed solution**

I tried using @ConditionalOnProperty and created an environment variable in some other class.(using ConfigurableEnvironment) (foo as true or false based on business logic that if username in configProperties is empty then foo is false, otherwise true). But the problem here is that for some reason spring searches for @ConditionalOnProperty and immediately checks application.property or environment variables at that time to see if that matches and then creates bean itself.
But execution order is first it checks @ConditionalOnProperty and it sees no variable in environment with that name and then it loads my other class. I have tried doing that in @PostConstruct too, but the priority of spring is fist @Conditional annotations then everything else. I have also tried using @DependsOn but that won't work too.

**3rd failed solution**
I have also tried using spring spel expression language but I am not able to form an spel expression that validates whether configProperties.username is null or not using @ConditionalOnExpression.

Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: what if datasource configuration is mandatory for running your tests or to spin up the application? How would you like to avoid creation of it? Maybe one thing could be that you careate your own `ConfigProperties` with configuration for your test database and mark it either with `@Primary` or create a `@TestConfiguration` class where you will create a new `ConfigProperties`

Comment: Or can't you just change configuration of that bean via application.(properties|yml|yaml) in tests? That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @bilak No, the database is not mandatory for running the database or for running the tests. Either way if I write some properties in yml file or if I create a configuration for test, i would expose the username, password, url info which I don't want to do. I would need to check how i can fetch config properties from cloud during test executions. But that should not be ideal solution for that.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand your needs. In test you would provide your own testing database (testcontainers for example) not some public available right?

Comment: @user3740495 did you ever come up with a solution for this? I have an oracle function that my spring app calls, and my plan is to mock my repository class in my tests but the spring app is complaining about missing datasource properties.